# Developing in Android Studio on 2 computers - and app.iml always changes

Tags: android, git, android-studio

I develop an Android app on 2 computers (using git to sync) - Windows 7 and Mac OS Yosemite.

For some reason the file **app.iml** is always changed when I open the project:

[image: diff screenshot]

Sorting dependencies in the **build.gradle** alphabetically hasn't helped:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:7.8.0'
    compile 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.vk:androidsdk:1.5.10'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
}
```

Can anything be done here? So that I am not forced to commit the changed file again and again?

I am using [.gitignore for Android](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Android.gitignore) recommended by GitHub.

Comment: So are you including the `.iml` files in `.gitignore` or not? Ideally if you are not changing the project configuration then you should put the `iml` file in git only.

Comment: I don't have `*.iml` in my `.gitignore` file (as in the file provided by GitHub).

Comment: @AlexanderFarber add *.iml in your .gitignore. In this way you will not share the file. Android Studio will create it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add it to your `.gitignore` file.  Then, run `git rm --cached app.iml` so that it's no longer tracked from that point on.  Considering that you're using Gradle for your dependencies, everyone else's local installation of Android Studio should be able to work with that as opposed to dealing with a shared `app.iml`.

While there are some JetBrains/IntelliJ/Android Studio project files that you *can* put into source control, my standing recommendation is not to, for this very reason:  you're going to have a lot of changes to those files that are not germane to the actual production code itself.

Comment: Yes, that would surely help - but: 1) GitHub's [.gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Android.gitignore) does not seem to recommend this 2) currently when `app.iml` is under source control - I can just checkout my project on any computer and immediately open it in Android Studio - without having to re-create the project. So I am looking for the root cause - why is Android Studio reordering lines in that file and how to stop it from doing that?

Comment: I would personally take GitHub's `.gitignore` more as a template and suggestion rather than an endorsement of what any one project should and shouldn't ignore.  I maintain that those files are rebuilt anyhow when one elects to import a project, so in my mind, there's little benefit in keeping it in source control if it's subject to radical changes.